# Elasticsearch - configure lowercase analyzer with no tokenizer

Tags: elasticsearch

Is there a way to configure an analyzer that will only lower case the input before indexing?

So for example if I get:

```
"name": "Foo Bar"
```

The output term should be "foo bar", so I can use a term query to query that exact term.

My use case is to index an entity that I am going to query later with a term query, so I want every thing to be index after lowercased.

Thanks!

Comment: @EvaldasBuinauskas, the floor is yours ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, found it!

Looks like the keyword tokenizer is the right tokenizer to use.

```
"analysis": {
  "analyzer": {
    "lowercase": {
      "type": "custom",
      "tokenizer": "keyword",
      "filter": [
        "lowercase"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: In NEST: `a => a.Analyzers(n => n.Custom("lowercase", c => c.Filters("lowercase").Tokenizer("keyword")))`